# Получение и обработка ссылки web view ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Есть приложение, в котором открывается веб-страница. На странице есть кнопки, ссылки которых содержат один и тот же ключ. Дк вот, как перед открытием страницы прогнать ссылку через if на наличие определенного фрагмента и принять решение, открыть в приложении или в safari?

Comment: у UIWebViewDelegate есть метод shouldStartLoadWith, делайте в нем свои проверки. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `UIWebViewDelegate` есть метод - `shouldStartLoadWith`.
Обязательно надо не забыть - `UIWebViewDelegate` при объявлении класса.

Если **Swift**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

Если **Objective-C**:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Ну и затем сам код:

Если **Swift**:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let url = request.url?.absoluteString
        if (url?.range(of: "#") != nil) {
            //url содержит знак - #
        }
        return true
    }
```

Если **Objective-C**:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"#"].location != NSNotFound) {
        //URL содержит знак #
    }
    return YES;
}
```